# ExecutorService SingleThreadExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have a list of objects, from which depending on user interaction some objects need to do work asynchronically. Something like this:

```
for(TheObject o : this.listOfObjects) {
   o.doWork();
}
```

The class `TheObject` implements an `ExecutorService` (SingleThread!), which is used to do the work. Every object of type TheObject instantiates an `ExecutorService`. I don't want to make [lasagna code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code#Lasagna_code). I don't have enough Objects at the same time, to make an extra extraction layer with thread pooling needed.

I want to cite the Java Documentation about [CachedThreadPools](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool%28%29):

> Threads that have not been used for sixty seconds **are terminated and
>   removed from the cache.** Thus, a pool that remains idle for long enough
>   **will not consume any resources.**

*First question:* Is this also true for a SingleThreadExecutor? Does the thread get terminated? JavaDoc doesn't say anything about SingleThreadExecutor. It wouldn't even matter in this application, as I have an amount of objects I can count on one hand. Just curiosity.

Furthermore the `doWork()` method of `TheObject` needs to call the `ExecutorService#.submit()` method to do the work async. Is it possible (I bet it is) to call the `doWork()` method implicitly? Is this a viable way of designing an async method?

```
void doWork() {
   if(!isRunningAsync) {
      myExecutor.submit(doWork());
   } else {
      // Do Work...
   }
}
```

Comment: A possibly better design would be for your TheObject class to accept an ExecutorService in its constructor and pass the same executor (not single threaded) to all your TheObject objects.

Comment: @assylias in that case wouldn't it be better to define a static threadpool inside that class?

Comment: That's an alternative indeed but gives you less control over the thread pool and is possibly less convenient for testing - depends on what your code does.

Comment: "...Is this also true for a SingleThreadExecutor?"  Trust the Javadoc.  Trust that the object returned by `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` will behave the way the Javadoc says it will behave.  And, don't make any assumptions about behavior that the Javadoc leaves unspecified (e.g., like whether or not the worker will terminate after a period of inactivity).  Behavior that is not specified may be implemented differently in different versions of the library or, on different platforms.

Answer (score 9):

> First question: Is this also true for a SingleThreadExecutor? Does the thread get terminated?

Take a look at the source code of [`Executors`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/Executors.java/), comparing the implementations of `newCachedThreadPool` and `newSingleThreadExecutor`:

```
public static ExecutorService newCachedThreadPool() {
    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                                  60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                                  new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());
}

public static ExecutorService newSingleThreadExecutor() {
    return new FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService
        (new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1,
                                0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()));
}
```

The primary difference (of interest here) is the `60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS` and `0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS`.

Effectively ([but not actually](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java#1313)), these parameters are passed to [`ThreadPoolExecutor.setKeepAliveTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#setKeepAliveTime-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-). Looking at the Javadoc of that method:

> A time value of zero will cause excess threads to terminate immediately after executing tasks.

where "excess threads" actually refers to "threads in excess of the core pool size".

- The cached thread pool is created with zero core threads, and an (effectively) unlimited number of non-core threads; as such, any of its threads can be terminated after the keep alive time.
- The single thread executor is created with 1 core thread and zero non-core threads; as such, there are no threads which can be terminated after the keep alive time: its one core thread remains active until you shut down the entire `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

(Thanks to @GPI for pointing out that I was wrong in my interpretation before).

Comment: This is not what I read from the doc. The one and only thread of a single thread pool is not an "excess thread", therefore, it is not bound to the doc you quoted (and in practice, you can check for yourself that a single thread executor that was submitted at least one work unit, and that is not shut down will keep its thread alive indefinitely).

Comment: @GPI aha. I think the thing that I was missing was that "excess threads" actually means "excess *non-core* threads" (as in the documentation of [`getKeepAliveTime(TimeUnit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#getKeepAliveTime-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)).

Comment: Good :) I was about to write about how surprised I was that it gets disposed. Can I assume, if it's not in the Docs it doesn't do it?

Comment: @ElMac No - you can only assume that if it isn't in the docs, then the behaviour is not publicly defined and thus might change.

Comment: @ElMac, by default, `Executors` created through the `ExecutorService` utility class spawn non-daemon threads. This can be altered when supplying your own `ThreadFactory` instead of the default `DefaultThreadFactory`

Answer (score 2):

**First question:**

> Threads that have not been used for sixty seconds are terminated and removed from the cache. Thus, a pool that remains idle for long enough will not consume any resources.
>
> **Is this also true for a SingleThreadExecutor?**

`SingleThreadExecutor` works differently. It don't have time-out concept due to the values configured during creation.

Termination of SingleThread is possible. But it guarantees that always one Thread exists to handle tasks from task queue.

From [newSingleThreadExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor--) documentation:

```
public static ExecutorService newSingleThreadExecutor()
```

> Creates an Executor that uses a single worker thread operating off an unbounded queue. (Note however that if this single thread terminates due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.)

Tasks are guaranteed to execute sequentially, and no more than one task will be active at any given time. Unlike the otherwise equivalent newFixedThreadPool(1) the returned executor is guaranteed not to be reconfigurable to use additional threads.

**Second question:**

> Furthermore the doWork() method of TheObject needs to call the ExecutorService#.submit() method to do the work async

```
for(TheObject o : this.listOfObjects) {
   o.doWork();
}
```

can be changed to

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Asynchronous task");
    }
});

executorService.shutdown();
```

with `Callable` or `Runnable` interface and add your `doWork`() code in `run()` method or `call()` method. The task will be executed concurrently.